# Dockerfile RUN command with passed argument

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-secrets

I'm trying to pass an argument to the docker build to have it executed in the Dockerfile as

```
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=$SECRET_NAME cp /run/secrets/$SECRET_NAME /etc/app/conf
```

but that will fail during the build time as

```
 > [8/8] RUN --mount=type=secret,id=mysecret cp /run/secrets/mysecret /etc/app/conf:
#13 0.224 cp: cannot stat '/run/secrets/mysecret': No such file or directory
```

but when I will use it directly in the `RUN` command as

```
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=mysecret cp /run/secrets/mysecret /etc/app/conf
```

that will work.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Does replacing `id=$SECERT_NAME` with `id=$SECRET_NAME` suffice?

Comment: @ErikMD LOL, nice catch. My typo when I was replaced specific name but that is not the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the feature you suggest ("environment variable expansion of the secret identifier itself") is just not supported by BuildKit, cf. the following two references:

- https://github.com/moby/buildkit/blob/master/frontend/dockerfile/docs/experimental.md#run---mounttypesecret
- https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#new-docker-build-secret-information

So maybe you could just refactor your Dockerfile so it does not require this feature (which by the way, would have the drawback to hinder legibility/reproducibility, given one could not know the secret identifier just by looking at the sole `RUN --mount=…` command).